# jquery mobile 1.4, change background color of certain buttons in select dialog list

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

With JQM 1.4, I would like to change the background-color of some particular buttons in a dialog list (only the ones that contain "SMALL"). I have recycled the code I was using with JQM 1.3 but without success : the buttons stay black (I use theme "b").

For now, I am simply adding a class to the `li` around the `a` button like this :

JS:

```
$('ul#chosenmodel-menu').find("a.ui-btn:contains(SMALL)").parent().addClass("optionfun");
```

CSS:

```
.optionfun {
    background-color: rgba(6, 180, 200, 0.3); /* blue in rgb, with transparency*/
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dT2g2/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change `background` of a *listview* item, you need to add custom classes to *anchor* `a` within *listview* item `li`.

A `select` with `data-native-menu="false"` is converted into either a *popup* or a *dialog* depending on screen height as well as number of *options*. In your case, the `select` is converted into a *dialog*, and *dialog* is a page. Hence, [*page events*](http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/) are emitted on it.

The *dialog* will receive an `id`, a combination of `select`'s `id` plus `-dialog`, e.g. `foo-dialog`. Add classes during `pagecontainerbeforeshow` event so the styles get applied before *dialog* is shown.

```
$(document).on("pagecontainerbeforeshow", function () {
    var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage");
    if (activePage[0].id == "chosenmodel-dialog") {
        $("ul li a:contains(SMALL)", activePage).addClass("optionfun");
    }
});
```

You can also do it without `!important`, just follow CSS specific selectors (a bit hectic but doable using firebug/dev tools).

```
.ui-page-theme-b .ui-btn.optionfun,
html body .ui-group-theme-b .ui-btn.optionfun,
html .ui-body-b .ui-btn.optionfun {
   background-color: rgba(6, 180, 200, 0.3);
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/by37F/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot @Omar for your very well put answer. I have simplified the css to `.optionfun` and added !important ...I am not sure it's the best practice, but it's so lighter !

Answer (score 2):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ukxrF/

This is only change:

```
.optionfun a {
        background-color: rgba(6, 180, 200, 0.3) !important;
}
```

Listview a tag has a background color and you need to override it using **!important** keyword.

Comment: It 's very weird because, thanks to your answer, now the background-color is well set when I inspect the elements with web inspector, but the color displayed is still black ! Do I have to refresh the listview in anyway or something ?

Comment: I would say that your listview is somewhat different then in this jsFiddle example because in example it works just fine (tested in Firefox and Chrome). And you dont need to refresh listview because you are forcing CSS to change background color. Are you testing this on jQuerey Mobile 1.3 or 1.4, I must know because you are mentioning both of them and HTML structure is different between jQM 1.3 and 1.4?

Comment: Then I don't know what's problem in your case. As you can see I gave you a working example. Some other CSS is probably affecting this one, I simply don0t have other explanation. Try using Firebug or browser developer tools and check if some other CSS class is causing this mismatch.

Comment: yes, thanks @Gajotres, I am going to try and find where is the problem

Comment: Ok I found it, I had a `.ui-btn` later in my css file, with a `background` css, and it was taking over my `bakcground-color`. Thanks !